# why does ggplotly() distort geom_dotplot() chart points

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

Given this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
fruit = c("Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "Mango", "Banana", "Apple", "Mango",
>            "Orange", "Mango", "Banana", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Orange",
>            "Mango", "Mango", "Apple", "Orange", "Mango", "Banana", "Apple", 
>            "Banana", "Apple", "Mango", "Banana", "Apple", "Mango", "Orange",
>            "Mango", "Banana", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Orange", "Mango",
>            "Mango", "Apple", "Orange", "Mango", "Banana"),
weight = c(3.85, 0.63, 1.12, 3.99, 1.76, 4.42, 1.54, 1.23, 4.73, 1.28,
1.95, 4.88, 1.15, 1.61, 2.55, 1.34, 4.07, 2.92, 1.43, 1.68,
2.30, 2.05, 2.45, 2.12, 2.75, 1.92, 2.64, 2.38, 3.88, 2.23,
2.97, 2.18, 2.36, 2.82, 3.65, 2.46, 2.19, 2.11, 2.59, 2.84)
> )
```

and these line of code, geom_dotplot() produces an expected plot

```
df$fruit <- as.factor(df$fruit)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = fruit, y = weight, fill = fruit)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', binpositions = "all") +
  labs(
    x = "Fruit",
    y = "Weight") +
  ylim(0, 5)

p1
```

the geom_dotplot() plot is here:
[image: geom_boxplot plot]

however, when I convert it with `plotly::ggplotly(p1)`, I get this image

[image: after ggplotly]

I have tried multiple arguments in the geom_dotplot layer like adjusting arguments `stackratio`, `dotsize`, `stackdir` and even `binwidth` but the ggplotly function never produces the same chart as the one created with `geom_dotplot()`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: [github issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1213) that may be related?

Comment: Alternatively, you could simply create a scatterplot like this: `p1 <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = weight, y = fruit, color = fruit)) +
  geom_point()

ggplotly(p1)`